# Помогите настроить синхронизацию между хостингом и github

Tags: github

Ребят, помогите плиз собрать раму с гитхабом.

Я тут решил бросить фриланс и устроится куданить в офис, разослал резюме, мне выслати тестовое задание.
Само задание могу сделать за 10 мин, но там есть условие:

Создать на Github репозитарий и при изменении в нем - обновлять код на сервере.

К серваку по ssh доступа нет, позже мне уточнили что я должен использовать webhook.

Нагуглил я такую вещь:
https://gist.github.com/gka/4627519

Забрал скрипт и конфиг к нему, в конфиге прописал username/repo, создал скрипт update.sh в него написал git pull origin master,

в конфиге путь поставил просто updete.sh т.к они в одной папке лежат, на гите у меня все отрабатывает (trigger-success. responce 200, все дела), но ничего на серве не происходит(

через echo **file**; посмотрел полный путь к текущей директории, попробовал в update.sh написать cd /var/www/dev10/public_html/ && git pull origin master
все глухо.

Потом обратил внимание что скрипт умеет слать ошибки на почту, чекнул а там :

> exception 'Exception' with message 'This does not appear to be a valid requests from Github.
>   ' in /var/www/dev10/public_html/git.php:65

как я понял там валидация стоит по ip:

```
$github_ips = array('207.97.227.253', '50.57.128.197', '108.171.174.178', '50.57.231.61');
```

и она по какойто причине не отрабатывает.
Помогите кто чем может, или подкинте рабочий скрипт)